# Is there some reason why I shouldn't use runtime.NumGoRoutines to wait for exit?

Tags: go, concurrency

I'm new to Go, and I'm writing some concurrent practice code using GoRoutines.

I've seen a lot of examples of worker pools using things like time.Sleep(), waitgroups, atomic counters, and channels to use various methods of determining when a pool of independent GoRoutines have completed their execution before ending a program.

Going through the GoLang reference I found the following library method:

`runtime.NumGoRoutines()` which returns a count of the currently executing number of Goroutines.

The following line:

`for runtime.NumGoroutine() > 1 {}`

Allows me to wait until all the GoRoutines have completed without dealing with any synchronizing code or speculative sleep durations.

In my testing, it's working perfectly to wait until all threads complete.
Is there something wrong with this technique I'm unaware of? It seems like the simplest possible method but since I have I never seen it used in any example code for this very common problem I'm suspicious that there's a reliability problem with it.

Comment: No, as there are no guaranties that all goroutines are started just by you: Any package and even the runtime may start goroutines at their discretion and keep them running. It is not the simplest technique, it's the most wrong.

Comment: Even if the condition you are checking were correct, spinning a cpu at 100% to wait for a condition is the least efficient method possible, and may also interfere with the scheduling of goroutines in the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend this practice, because you have a busy loop there that uses an unnecessary amount of CPU power.

When working with goroutines I always recommend [WaitGroup](https://gobyexample.com/waitgroups).
You should know the number of goroutines, then wait for them to finish without using 100% CPU.